# How to add a timer to one picture out of multiple pics on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this HTML code to just show pictures on a browser, every click transitions to the next picture. My question is how can i make Slide13 automatically go to Slide14 after 4 seconds then go back to clicking to transition between pictures? Thanks!!

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Slide1.PNG</title>
  </head>
  <body onclick="step()">
        <img id="image_id" src="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">


    var images=[
            "Slide1.PNG",
                "Slide2.PNG",
                "Slide3.PNG",
                "Slide4.PNG",
          "Slide5.PNG",
          "Slide6.PNG",
          "Slide7.PNG",
          "Slide8.PNG",
          "Slide9.PNG",
          "Slide10.PNG",
          "Slide11.PNG",
          "Slide12.PNG",
          "Slide13.GIF",
          "Slide14.PNG",
          "Slide15.GIF",
          "Slide16.PNG",
          "Slide17.PNG",
          "Slide18.PNG",
          "Slide19.PNG",
          "Slide20.GIF",
          "Slide21.PNG",
          "Slide22.PNG",
          "Slide23.PNG",
          "Slide24.PNG",
          "Slide25.PNG",
          "Slide26.PNG",
          "Slide27.PNG",
          "Slide28.PNG",
          "Slide29.PNG",
          "Slide30.PNG",
          "Slide31.PNG",
          "Slide32.PNG",
          "Slide33.PNG",
          "Slide34.PNG"
            ];



        var index=0;
        var imageObjects=images.map(function(img){var imgTag=new Image();imgTag.src=img});
        function step(){
            document.getElementById('image_id').src=images[(index++)%images.length];
        }
        step();
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your step:

```
    var image = document.getElementById("image_id").src;
                if (image=="Slide13.GIF") {
                     setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('image_id').click();}, 4000);      
                }
```

It will check on every step the source value of image, when it hits Slide13.GIF it will emulate the click on it after 4 seconds and go to next one.

See below demo, on 3ed image it will click it after 2 seconds.

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Slide1.PNG</title>
  </head>
  <body onclick="step()">
        <img id="image_id" src="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">


    var images=[
            "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.zYTlTH6b_YYEeNCvZsznjgHaD5%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
                "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.ZJA-xTrw2bHQaUXA6buoGwHaDt%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
                "https://media2.giphy.com/media/YmbxC8Bkj9bZ4yu4Le/source.gif",
                "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.qz01j4K29bmGqCy1hIwGswHaFf%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
          "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2Fea490bc9d89afaf7d2431a0374aef65c%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D15761601&f=1&nofb=1",
          "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.wae3QtVQ_QQvkeaQ3alxzgHaEY%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
          "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.xd0rh27OUOrMUw8_ACG0HwHaDt%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
          "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.adQHsWv9A37aVRLNDLLlkwHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
          "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.3nRZ72gyQTUakC-ZbhQ_MQHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1"
            ];



        var index=0;
        var imageObjects=images.map(function(img){var imgTag=new Image();imgTag.src=img});
        function step(){
            document.getElementById('image_id').src=images[(index++)%images.length];
            var image = document.getElementById("image_id").src;
            console.log(image);
            if (image=="https://media2.giphy.com/media/YmbxC8Bkj9bZ4yu4Le/source.gif" || image=="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2Fea490bc9d89afaf7d2431a0374aef65c%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D15761601&f=1&nofb=1") {
              setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('image_id').click(); }, 3000);    
            }
        }
        step();
        </script>


</html>
```

**EDIT:**

It does work with gifs, i Just added two of them, on step 3 and 5. Also if you need more conditions in your if statement separate them with  || Like so:

```
    if (image=="https://media2.giphy.com/media/YmbxC8Bkj9bZ4yu4Le/source.gif" || 
image=="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.tenor.com%2Fimages%2Fea490bc9d89afaf7d2431a0374aef65c%2Ftenor.gif%3Fitemid%3D15761601&f=1&nofb=1") {
```

As seen in edited demo now it will do a click on two gifs, number 3 and 5.
You can add `console.log(image);` below image variable to see correct image source and use that in condition.

If you have problems with finding paths you can use this as your conditions:

```
if (image.indexOf("Slide13.GIF") >= 0 || image.indexOf(" other pic ") >= 0")
```

This will check if image variable of source value contains your wanted image title.

Comment: This is great thank you so much! If i want to do it to multiple slides do i just add another IF(Image) statement?

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working after the gif.

var index=0;
        var imageObjects=images.map(function(img){var imgTag=new Image();imgTag.src=img});
        function step(){
            document.getElementById('image_id').src=images[(index++)%images.length];
            var image = document.getElementById("image_id").src;
            if (image=="Slide13.GIF") {
              setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('image_id').click(); }, 2000);    
            }
        }
        step();
        </script>

Comment: @mfaubion You are doing something wrong on your side. This works, I edited a demo with two gifs and added second condition to skip two gifs. See edited part of post. Check your console.log for possible errors.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the PNG's that i just have in the folder vs you linking them from a site?

Comment: @mfaubion No, as log as you use correct source path. Just tasted this on localhost with files, it works, use your console.log(image), to see correct full path to your image and use that in your conditions like i mentioned. For me it was: http://localhost:8888/img-test/image_name_here... Do same thing on hosting server, with his paths.

Comment: @mfaubion See my last edit, you can use image.indexOf("Slide13.GIF") to find if source contains your image title and use that as condition without specifying full path.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a look. I did just do the same thing but used images that are online and it worked. I do believe that it has something to do with images on my local machine because it displays the local pictures just fine but not the auto click.

Comment: The index line did it. Thank you sooo much for your time!!! @ikiK